# Group by hours in SQLAlchemy - how?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I'd like to see how many rows created per hours in a table, based on a timestamp field.
If I use rdbms specific functions, it is simple, but I need a solution which doesn't depend on the rdbms. Therefore the sqlalchemy.func is out of the question - the pythonic way (itertools.group by) is excluded too, because it generates very high traffic between the database and my application.
I'm using sqlalchemy 1.4 (with Flask if it is important)

Comment: I doubt whether it is possible without using `func`... Maybe you should have an `adapter` and use different function depending on database?

Comment: I fear, you're right...

Comment: Another option is using `func` and defining custom function at database level that would parse hour from timestamp. You would have the same behaviour in each database but you have to put this function into each database that is used.

Comment: Dear jorzel, as I wrote, I want to keep my program's rdbms-independent state. The sqlalchemy.func uses database specific code. For example, it accepts func.date_trunc,  it is working with PostgreSQL backend, but not with MySQL or Oracle.

Comment: I understand, so I recommend you writing your own function or adapter, like: if 'postgres' take `date_trunc`, elif 'oracle' take `to_char`elif 'mysql' take `hour`, etc.